# MFC without document/view architecture

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc

I'd like some help on using MFC without the document/view architecture.

I created a project without doc/view support, Visual C++ created a **CFrameWnd** and a view that inherits from **CWnd**. I replaced the view inheriting from **CWnd** with a new view that inherits from **CFormView**.

However, when I run my program, after I close the window I get a heap corruption error.

Comment: I don't understand "_view inheriting from CWnd with a new view that inherits from CFormView_".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is MFC's lifecycle management. The view declaration (created by Visual C++ wizard) is:

```
CChildView        m_wndView;
```

I replaced the above code with:

```
CChildFormView    m_wndView;
```

CChildView inherits from **CWnd**, CChildFormView inherits from **CFormView**. Both views were created by the wizard, but only CChildFormView uses the **DECLARE_DYNCREATE**/**IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE** macros.

Since m_wndView is being created in the stack, when MFC automagically calls delete I get the error.

Comment: I don't understand how changing the name from CChildView to CChildFormView changes how the application builds or executes, those names are names we provide, not names of MFC classes. I doubt that this has any relevance for anyone else. Many years ago I wrote an article describing how to create a MFC CFormView application without document/view architecture. It was not easy to do, at least not then.

Answer (score 4):

If inside where the frame window handles WM_CREATE, you change the code to create the instance of CFormView with the "magic" id of AFX_IDW_PANE_FIRST, you'll find it becomes the view for the frame window.  This is due to the behaviour of CFrameWnd::InitialUpdateFrame(), which will be called from within MFC. The MSDN page comments on this helpful little feature:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch3t7308.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to use the dialog editor and you don't want the document/view architecture, then maybe a "Dialog based" application is what you need.